# How to Force Refresh on the Access Token When Using Azure.Identity Lib DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

I'm relying on [DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential.gettoken?view=azure-dotnet)  to get access token and auth my app to put/get resouurces on Azure. But looks like it doesn't mention how to do a force refresh on the access token. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, token lifecycle is managed automatically by the SDK and it automatically gets a new access token as and when needed. Can you describe your use case for forcefully refreshing an access token?

Comment: @GauravMantri yeah true. Basically i do a PUT request on the resource and then try a GET but received access deny. This is due to the ARM role assignment cache. So I was told using a new access token on GET the resource it would also force a refresh on the ARM role assignment cache.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Getting a new access won’t solve the issue for you. I would recommend editing your question and describe the problem you’re facing or you can post a new question regarding that.

Comment: @GauravMantri. It does work for me. I will keep the question as it is.

Comment: To give another scenario - making use of Privileged Identity Management for Azure AD Groups. We have Role based access assigned to Groups. If a user has already obtained a token before granting themselves membership in a group using PIM, the new group won't appear in their access token until it gets refreshed. This means that any requests to Azure resources don't have their full group membership.